# Scoverage with ScalaJs Cross Build Project on Play Framework

Tags: scala, scala.js, scoverage, playscalajs

I am working on a ScalaJs cross build application on Play Framework and want to use scoverage to check the coverage but I get linking errors. I went through some materials online and the information there seems to suggest that as of now it may not be possible to do so. But I really want to be sure and so is there any way that scoverage can be used with ScalaJs cross build project??

Answer (score 1):

There were requests for ScalaJS support, there two PRs:
https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen+Scala.js+
and some issues:
https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+ScalaJs
but no work was done.

Comment: Thankyou for the response.

Comment: Actualization: ScalaJS is supported by sbt-scoverage plugin since version 1.4.0